# Divide by 10, hash and then divide by 10 again until cc is less than 1

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to separate individual numbers within a credit card number so I can perform a "checksum" on them. This is the problem explination https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/1/credit/.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    //Get a number at least the length of the shortest possible credit card number
    long cc;
    do
    {
        cc = get_long("Credit Card Number:");
    }
    while (cc < 1300000000000);
    
    int a = cc % 10;

    int b = cc % 100/10;
 
    int c = cc % 1000/100;
    
    printf("last%i second to last %i, third to last", a,b);
    
}
```

Is there some better way to implement this? I just want to get the %10 remainder and record the variable for that value. And then keep moving over the number until I have each individual number recorded in individual variables. Then I can manipulate all the numbers independently.

Comment: Please add the cs50 tag so I can properly ignore te question.

Comment: Use a for loop, multiplying your divider value by 10 each time?

Comment: If you're validating credit card numbers, you need to use the Luhn algorithm. This can be implemented with a simple `for()` loop, as described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Pseudocode_implementation)

Comment: This question should be asked on [cs50.se] instead, which is being created just for that purpose.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I wasn't aware that existed. Sorry for the bother fellas.

Comment: a `long` can hold any number up to 2147483647  but credit card numbers are much bigger.  So you either need to take the credit card number as a string or use a `long long` variable which will hold any number up to  9223372036854775807

Comment: Also, like another commenter said, you can do it with individual digit variables but a loop is much less code. https://onlinegdb.com/BkDNNlgBu

Comment: Here is an example using a loop: https://onlinegdb.com/BktH3egHd